# explicit formula for embedding projective spaces into euclidean space

Tags: differential-topology

i can't seem to find very many good answers for this. most of the theorems out there use cohomology methods (Stiefel-Whitney classes, etc.) for proving that projective spaces can be embedded into Euclidean spaces of certain dimensions. Don Davis has a good table of minimal embedding dimensions. this paper (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926224508000661) has some explicit formulas for *isometric* embeddings of projective spaces into Euclidean spaces, but the dimension of the target gets pretty large. for example the minimal dimension for an isometric embedding of RP^5 is 20, but it can be embedded in R^9. the question is: where can i find an explicit formula for such an embedding? or is there at least some procedure for me to figure one out? or am i just stuck running through the Whitney embedding theorem to try to get explicit maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Not sure if you are asking for any concrete embedding to $\Bbb{P^n(R)}\to \Bbb{R}^{N_n}$ or for one with $N_n$ small (if so look at this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/329931/transitive-embedding-of-the-projective-plane-bbb-r-p2-into-the-4-sphere)). Anyway it is worth mentioning that for $N_n=n+1+n(n+1)/2$ it works and the embedding has a particularly simple expression.

$\Bbb{P^n(R)}$ is homeomorphic to $S^n/\pm 1$ through $$[p_0:\ldots:p_n] \to \pm (\frac{p_0}{\|p\|},\ldots,\frac{p_n}{\|p\|}), \qquad \|p\|=\sqrt{\sum_j p_j^2}$$

$S^n/\pm 1$ is a variety with coordinate ring $\Bbb{R}[S^n]^{\pm 1}$, the subring of $$\Bbb{R}[S^n]=\Bbb{R}[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/(\sum_{j=0}^n x_j^2-1)$$ fixed by $x\to -x$.

$$\Bbb{R}[S^n]^{\pm 1}= \Bbb{R}[ \{ \prod_{j=0}^n x_j^{e_j},2| \sum_j e_j \}]/I=\Bbb{R}[\{x_ix_j\}_{i\le j}]/I$$
 (where $/I$ is to recall those are polynomial rings quotiented by the ideal of functions vanishing on $S^n$)

> That's it we have found an embedding $\Bbb{P^n(R)}\to S^n/\pm 1\to \Bbb{R}^{n+1+n(n+1)/2}$ which is 
>   $$[p_0:\ldots:p_n] \to  \pm (\frac{p_0}{\|p\|},\ldots,\frac{p_n}{\|p\|})\to (\frac{p_0p_0}{\|p\|^2},\ldots,\frac{p_ip_j}{\|p\|^2},\ldots,\frac{p_np_n}{\|p\|^2})$$